# Increasing the speed of nested for loops

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently trying to solve a problem for work, so I'm sorry the code is going to have to be a little vague but the concept is simple enough that I should be able to convey my issue without being specific.

The end goal is to take two variables (X, Y), I need to run X against every single Y. The sample data I have been provided (not even half of it) is X = 107 and Y = 6400, so we're looking at 684,800 iterations just for the sample data. This is obviously going to take a while, but I want to do my best to shrink the time where possible.

I have tried two different ways, one being nested for loops, and one was my attempt at running it in parallel, but to be honest I don't have much experience with parallelism so I can see why it didn't work. Both scenarios ran the same length of time before I encountered an error that is unrelated to the issue at hand (3.5 hours)

I have tried a couple different ways of loading in both CSVs using ParameterizedTest that I couldn't get to work, so if there is an easy way using JUnit I would LOVE to hear it. I'm currently using JUnit 5.3.1.

Attempt 1:

```
@Test
void test() {
    List<String> varX = loadCsv(path);
    List<String> varY = loadCsv(otherPath);

    for (String x : varX) {
        for (String y : varY) {
            // Do the work
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
@Test
void test() {
    List<String> varX = loadCsv(path);
    List<String> varY = loadCsv(otherPath);

    varX.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
        for (String x : varX) {
            for (String y : varY) {
                // Do the work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Attempt2 might run faster thanks to parallelism, but watch out: you have one level of of nesting added by accident. Remove the outer for look within the forEach

Comment: Attempt 2 is not correct. You've looped xVar again inside parallelStream. `varX.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
           varY.parallelStream().forEach(y ->{
                // Do the work with x and y
            }
        }
    }`............ Anyway optimizing running time depends on the task that you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding using a `@ParameterizedTest` - you could load both CSV, map them to a `Stream<Arguments>` and parameterize the test method to use them:

```
public static Stream<Arguments> loadTestData() {
    List<String> varX = loadCsv(path);
    List<String> varY = loadCsv(otherPath);

    return varX.parallelStream()
               .flatMap(x -> varY.parallelStream().map(y -> Arguments.of(x, y)));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("loadTestData")
void test(String x, String y) {
    // You now have a combination of x and y:
    // test that the logic under test works for that combination
}
```

Comment: Perfect this worked for me, thanks a lot! I didn't think about using MethodSource, I just had a one track mind about loading in two CSVs using one of the CSV annotations.